# SQL LEFT JOIN return 0 rather than NULL

Tags: sql, null, left-join

I want to join two tables, with the number of records for each type being counted. If there are no records of that type in the left table I want a 0 to be returned, not a null.

How can I do this?

Comment: What type of database? SQL Server, MySql, Oracle, ...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use:

```
ISNULL(count(*), 0)
```

Comment: This would be valid if count(*) returned NULL for no records. However count(*) returns 0. So count(*) and ISNULL(count(*),0) are effectively the same.

Answer (score 26):

You can use "CASE"

```
SELECT T1.NAME, CASE WHEN T2.DATA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T2.DATA END
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: good job bro. I used it by sum() function and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

```sql
COALESCE(XXX, 0)
```

E.g.

```sql
SELECT branch1_id, branch1_name, COALESCE(devnum, 0) FROM
    branch1 as S LEFT JOIN view_inner_zj_devnum as B ON S.branch1_id = B.bid1 GROUP BY branch1_id;
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 13):

`ISNULL(nullable, value_if_null)` for MsSQL, `COALESCE(nullable1, nullable2, ..., value_if_null)` for MySQL.

**Edit:**
As I'm told, `COALESCE` works for both, so I'd choose that to replace `NULL` columns.

Now I think that `COUNT()`ing `NULL` values returns `0` in MySQL too, so I agree with Rashmi. Could you show us the query and the wanted result ?

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if I have understood your exact problem, but in sqlserver on a left join,
you will get a count as 0 if your query is something like this:

```
select t1.id, count(t2.id)
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

Comment: That's a good point. In my answer I didn't make any assumptions as to how this count was done.

Answer (score 7):

COALESCE is more cross-compatible than ISNULL or NVL (it works on MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL, Derby, et al.). But I am not sure about the performance differences.

Comment: That's true, but there are usually better ways to abstract out DB difference that by writing non DB specific SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210(SQL.80).aspx) in SQL Server and [Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks162.htm). Use [NVL](http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2005/10/oracle-nvl-microsoft-isnull.html) in Oracle.

Comment: @Andomar. As Karl hasn't described how he is doing the count (using a count function) or even what database is used, making the assumption that count is the correct answer is wrong. Presumably Karl is not using count as others have correctly pointed out in SQL Server at least this will return 0.

Comment: For example- Karl could be selecting a column NumberOfItems. If however Karl is using Count, then the question is incorrect.